# How to open a specific tab in a different page

Tags: html, tabs

I have a home page on which, inside an IFrame a different HTML page is shown. 
On that page there's a link, which on click, needs to open another page inside the same IFrame with specific tab shown. The new page has 3 tabs and the link need to open the second one. 
There are other links too, which needs to open specific tabs. The problem is all this is for a demo purpose and no dynamic setting is there. No database or anything. All are static HTML pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="http://someserver.com/somepage.html#tab2" target="_self">Tab 2</a>`

assuming the page can parse the hash